# Error: Unexpected field. using uploadMultiple from dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dropzone.js, multer

I wanted to have a way so users can choose images to send with a review.

so I use dropzone.js . It seems like having problems sending multiple images in one request. I thought that req.files would contain an array of files but that didn't happen. right now I see a problem because dropzone adds `[]` with the indexes inside for the name param.

when adding to images to dropzone I see something like this in request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryJOpGX6kWaoknKhIN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[0]"; filename="data.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryJOpGX6kWaoknKhIN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[1]"; filename="loginButton.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryJOpGX6kWaoknKhIN--
```

I feel like `[0]` and `[1]` is causing me problems

server:

```
app.post("/files" , upload.array("images"), (req, res) =>{
    console.log("hit here")
    console.log("req.file :", req.file)
    // console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.files)
    res.send("ok")
})
```

simple multer: I had more complicated one before

`var upload = multer({ dest: "./uploads" })`

frontend:

```
<script src = "/dropzone.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var myDropZone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
            url : "/files",
            // uploadMultiple : true,

            autoProcessQueue : false,
             parallelUploads: 5,
            paramName: "images",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            init : function(){
                this.on("success", function(){
                    // alert("success")
                })
                this.on("sendingmultiple", function(){
                    console.log("SENDING MULTIPLE");
                })
                this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response){
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(files);
                })
            } 
        })
            $("#skip, #login").on("click", function(e){
                myDropZone.processQueue();
            })
    })

</script>
<div class = "dropzone"></div>
   <div id = "skip"> skip </div>
   <div id = "login">login</div>
```

when I get rid of `uploadMultiple: true,` I get the images in the FS but it looks like multiple post request were made there is no `req.files` array with multiple images. I thought there would be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to force the name by specifying a function for `paramName` instead of a string:

```
paramName: function() { return 'images'; },
```

which will prevent any suffixes from being added to the form fields.

Comment: This looks really good. I thought I followed the documentation clearly and this was getting me stuck. I didn't know that I should use a function. Now I see the array in the `files` I will accept this answer when I do more testing later. Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: I stuck with this problem and didn't know how to resolve. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this method, but it is still failed and return me "unexpected field". any ideas ?